# What about the MIPS instructions is correct?

Tags: mips, instructions

In which of the above instructions is done writing in a register?

a) lw 
b) bne 
c) beq 
d) sll 
e) sw 
f) add

I'm sure for d) and f) but I also think that a) and e) are correct. What do you think?

Comment: SO is not a homework service. Please see [ask]. Concerning your problem, you miss a obvious one. And what is a register? Is PC a register? Maybe this will add extra yes answers?

Comment: In general register, not specified which type...Just that writes in register.

Answer (score 0):

So Think about the general 5 stage pipeline used in MIPS F,D,E,M,W. (fetch, decode, execute, memory, write)

lw -> you are LOADING something from memory into variable (ends in write) 
sw -> you are taking a variable and writing into memory (ends in write)

Comment: No. only the LW. LW writes to a register. SW writes to memory